# waiting for multiple processes to finish with expect

Tags: expect

Am looking for a construct in expect to watch for output from multiple jobs and not complete until all have returned expected output or have timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Read about indirect spawn ids.  This works now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

spawn echo 0 Passed
set list $spawn_id

spawn echo 1 Passed
set list "$list $spawn_id"
set waiting_cnt [llength $list]

send_user "list is '$list', length $waiting_cnt\n"

set timeout 2

expect {
    -i list eof {
        set index [lsearch $list $expect_out(spawn_id)]
        set list  [lreplace $list $index $index]
        if [llength $list] exp_continue
    }

    -i list -re Passed {
        send_user "passed seen on $expect_out(spawn_id)\n"
        incr waiting_cnt -1
        exp_continue
    }
}

send_user "both seem to have passed, waiting_cnt = $waiting_cnt\n"
```